# C# Back to main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have login form as my app main window and it will hide when user successfully logged in then shows another form.

The issue is, That when user closes other form(s) I cannot show login form again.

**PS:** I've tried to show login form with help of FormClosed event and it did show my login form but when I closed my login form it did not close the application. (my app was still running on debug mode while there was no opening window)

**Code**

This is my login code *(works fine)*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If both UserName and Password fields are filled try to run DB check
    if (usernameBox.Text != "" && passwordBox.Text != "")
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPOS.Properties.Settings.IPOSDatabaseString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cn.Open();
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.LoginUser", cn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", usernameBox.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordBox.Text);

                        SqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (result.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (result.Read())
                            {
                                // Open mainWindow when user is loggedIn
                                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                                this.Hide(); <-- hide login form (window)
                                mainWindow.Show();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cn.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine("res {0}", result);
                            MessageBox.Show("Your credentials are not match!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                    "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                    "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                    "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                    "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill both fields.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

**Issues**

1. When I close `MainWindow()` this `Login()` form wont show
2. If I show `Login()` form by help of `FormClosed` event in `MainWindow()` closing `Login()` will not shoutdown the application.

**Logic (Expected behavior)**

1. Show login on opening *(Done)*
2. After login show mainWindow *(done)*
3. If mainWindow, closed show login
4. If login closed, shoutdown the app.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Woah ... you have a big mixture of UI code and business logic code. Sooner or later, this will get you in trouble. Probably sooner, i.e. right now. Please read about clean code, single responsibility and MVP or MVVM patterns. Don't tie your business logic (database) code and your UI code so tighly together.

Comment: It might help showing the mainForm as modal with ShowDialog instead of Show. Codeflow will stop there until you close the mainForm. So you can show the form again after the call to ShowDIalog. If that help you should rearange your code to not let the connection for login in open while your mainform is shown. Or even better choose a different approach completely.

Comment: @Ralf: you probably mean ShowDialog().

Comment: @ThomasWeller. Presumably i mixed up different techniques. Again ;)

Comment: IMHO, this is not just an issue of "fix this line here". You can get away with it for a moment, but your app really needs an architectural redesign. Do you have a software architect or experienced software developer in your company? Maybe someone who can work in TDD style?

Comment: @ThomasWeller and Ralf Appreciate your comments but I'm totally newbie with C# and visual studio in general, would that be possible to show me some sample code /or links so I get the idea of what I should change?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No I do not have experience in software development as I said I'm newbie in it but what issue do you see in this code? because this basically just validate user exist in database and shows some errors if user hasn't filled all fields nothing special!

Comment: @ThomasWeller as much as I understood is best to use `Stored Procedures` to avoid SQL injection **which I do** and is best to put my DB codes inside `using()`'s **Which I do** etc. I'm not really sure what bad things you're seeing in my code to be called `not clean code` Also I'm running my code in `try` and `catch`...

Comment: The thing that the login form should be shown again when main form closes is that a real requirement? It feels weird for a desktop application.

Comment: @Ralf so the idea behind it is if user closes mainWindow means user is logged out therefore nobody else can do things while that user is away. So the user must re-login to work with the app again.

Comment: @Ralf even if we say no need to show login page, yet by closing mainWindow form will not shutdown the app, it just closes the form but app is running in debug

Comment: @mafortis. I asked because that is pretty non standard behaviour. When looking at a fitting tutorial for you presumably none would consider this.

Comment: @Ralf please share your idea it might be better than mine and I use your way (why not?!)

Comment: Checkout the following [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53316.sql-server-database-login-for-windows-forms-c.aspx) with code. Login logic resides in a class project while the login form only has code to collect user name and password. When passing credentials to the database,  [SqlCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) Class is used for securing a password. Two minor changes will allow re-showing the login form if so desired.

Comment: @KarenPayne thank you for heads up (I will definitely use securing password) but what are the changes that help me show back login form `Two minor changes will allow re-showing the login form if so desired` ?

Comment: In the Main form, don't use  `MainFormClosed event`, in the Login form, after `mainForm.ShowDialog();` add `Show();`

Comment: @KarenPayne so all of my issue would have solved with this `mainWindow.ShowDialog(); Show();`? :))) Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I made these changes and then closing the main form, the login form is presented again.

One last thing, don't simply use the code, instead I suggest taking time to study the code.  Its always best to understand the code presented.

Comment: @KarenPayne yes it also worked for me too, and yes I am trying to understand `SqlCredential` then I will find out why I should have need that extra `Show();` :) appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

3. Add FormClosing event in mainWindow and show Login form.

   private void mainWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
   frmLogin frmL= new frmLogin();
   frmL.Show();
   }
4. Add FormClosed event in Login and Close the app.

   private void frmLogin_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
   {
   Application.Exit();
   }